# Razor syntax all has the "red squiggly" in all projects?

Tags: model-view-controller, visual-studio

About a week ago all my MVC projects have the razor syntax underlined with red squiggly lines, but they all compile and run fine?

I have tried uninstalling MVC, and uninstalling and re-installing VS, with no solution. I am running VS2013 Premium Version 12.0.21005.1.

Anyone else experienced this? How did you fix it?